# For com horário em python

Tags: python

Bom dia Pessoal!
Alguém pode me ajudar se é possível criar um `for` em `Python` que utilize horários?

**Exemplo:**

> Setar um horário de inicio do `for` e outro de termino e a **cada 1 hora** esse `for` seja executado novamente.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

atual = now.hour
hr_final = 10
i = 0

for i in range(int(hr_final - atual)):
    print (atual)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de forma simples usando o método sleep do módulo time

veja um exemplo de código que executa a cada 1 hora.

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

hora = 3600

while True:
    print datetime.now()
    sleep(hora)
```

No código acima setamos o método sleep para "esperar" 3600 segundos que da 1 hora

Comment: Muito obrigado RickADT, era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando.

Answer (score 3):

Não creio que seja possível utilizar um for com uma data para o propósito que vc quer.

cálculos, operações e afins envolvendo dada são famosos por obter um certo nível de 'complexidade' inerente.

Acho que vc deveria aumentar o escopo da pergunta e perguntar-se:

> 'É possível ter um script que se executa a cada 1 hora ?'

Existem varias formas de se fazer isso, creio que uma da mais simples (vou cita-la como exemplo somente para que vc teste) é utilizando uma biblioteca apropriada. O [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) é uma biblioteca guiada a eventos que pode ser usada para executar códigos em intervalos de tempo:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, task
from os.path import getsize

FILE = '/var/log/syslog'

def monitor(lastsize = [-1])
    size = getsize(FILE)
    if size <> lastsize[0]:
        print 'O tamanho do arquivo agora é %d kilobytes (%d bytes)' % \
              (round(size / 1024.0), size)
        lastsize[0] = size

if __name__ == '__main__'
    print 'Checando a cada um minuto o tamanho do arquivo "%s".' % FILE
    print 'Atenção: esse programa NUNCA termina.'
    l = task.LoopingCall(monitor)
    l.start(1.0)
    reactor.run()
```

Esse código por exemplo checa o tamanho do arquivo a cada 1 segundo. Entretanto o uso de uma biblioteca tão grande e complexa como essa apenas para usar uma simples funcionalidade **NÃO** é recomendado, seria como usar um foguete para matar um mosquito.

Para uma solução implementada por si só recomendo fortemente que [**leia esse artigo postado na Python Brasil**](https://wiki.python.org.br/ExecutandoEmIntervalos). Lá é demonstrado 3 exemplos de como executar códigos em intervalos pre determinados de maneira simples e bem explicada.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer apenas fazer o incremento dos valores, assim use o objeto `timedelta` em conjunto com o `datetime` para aumentar ou diminuir variáveis com data e tempo:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

inicio = datetime.now()

for i in range(0,10):
    print inicio + timedelta(hours=i)
```

E obter como resultado:

```
2018-12-24 11:23:44.750000
2018-12-24 12:23:44.750000
2018-12-24 13:23:44.750000
2018-12-24 14:23:44.750000
2018-12-24 15:23:44.750000
2018-12-24 16:23:44.750000
2018-12-24 17:23:44.750000
2018-12-24 18:23:44.750000
2018-12-24 19:23:44.750000
2018-12-24 20:23:44.750000
```

Você pode usar "seconds", "minutes", "days", "months" etc, sozinhos ou em conjunto para incrementar (ou decrementar) seu objeto `datetime`.